# Why does math operation on large numbers sometimes need an intermediary variable to return a correct result?

Tags: vba, excel

I have been using Excel 2013 here. For example,

```
Public Function RoundTest(ByVal flNumber As Double) As Double
  RoundTest = Round(flNumber)
End Function

Public Function Test( _
    ByVal flNumber As Double, _
    ByVal flDivisor As Double) _
    As Double

  Test = flNumber - (RoundTest(flNumber / flDivisor) * flDivisor)
End Function
```

Let `flDivisor` is passed as **10** by caller. Calling `Test()` with `flNumber` <= **10^22** yields a correct result, that is **0**, but with `flNumber` > **10^22**, `Test()` returns a wrong result, that is a negative number. However, if an intermediary variable is used to temporarily hold the partial result of the calculation, `Test()` returns a correct result, that is **0**.

```
Public Function Test( _
    ByVal flNumber As Double, _
    ByVal flDivisor As Double) _
    As Double
  Dim flTemp As Double

  flTemp = RoundTest(flNumber / flDivisor) * flDivisor
  Test = flNumber - flTemp
End Function
```

Why does this happens? How can I avoid this peculiarity?

Comment: Looks like a [floating-point precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) issue to me.

Comment: @Comintern - If the issue is floating-point precision, using an intermediary variable to temporarily hold the partial result of the calculation (as in my example) should also returns a wrong result.

Comment: Not necessarily. Each *calculation* can introduce floating point errors.

Comment: @Comintern: acknowledged, +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is more straightforward example:

```
Public Function RoundTest(ByVal flNumber As Double) As Double
    RoundTest = Round(flNumber)
End Function

Sub TestCDbl()
    Dim a As Double
    Dim b As Double
    a = 10 ^ 23
    b = 10
    w1 = a - RoundTest(a / b) * b ' -8388608
    w2 = a - Round(a / b) * b ' 0
    w3 = a - CDbl(RoundTest(a / b) * b) ' 0

End Sub
```

IMO intrinsic implementation of calculations works so that results of native `Round()` function and returned from `RoundTest()` function are processed in different ways. Also turns out it may process any part of expression and particularly subtrahend not as double type, and having explicit conversion to double with `CDbl()` might help in your case, instead of coercion by assigning to temp variable of double type.
You have to bear in mind that this effort and suchlike do not guarantee to fix the issue. Each calculation can introduce floating point errors, as @Comintern commented.

Comment: @omega-stripes: Thanks, your answer helps me to understand what is going on behind the scene.